# Opposite of `bind_rows()` to return to a list

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I have a list that has to be converted to a table, but has to return to its list state.

```r
li <- list(list(id = 1, v = 2), list(id = 1, v = 3)) 

tab <- dplyr::bind_rows(li)
tab
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     id     v
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2
2     1     3
```

How do I return to `li` ?

Edit: purrr::transpose does the trick. # now superseded

Edit 2: as.list() |> purrr::list_transpose() does it

```r
purrr::list_transpose(as.list(tab))
[[1]]
[[1]]$id
[1] 1

[[1]]$v
[1] 2


[[2]]
[[2]]$id
[1] 1

[[2]]$v
[1] 3
```

Comment: That worked. I like the `purrr::transpose()` solution!

Comment: If you want one row per df, there is also `lapply(row.names(tab), \(i) tab[i,])`, not in @SamR's linked question .

Comment: What about `purrr::pmap(tab, ~ list(...))`?